# Change view *while* another is being pressed

Tags: android

I want to know
how to change the properties of some view while another is being pressed?

for example a textview changes it's color while another button is being pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register an [`OnTouchListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) for the `View` which is pressed and change the `TextView`'s properties there in the [`onTouch`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch(android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent)) method.

Comment: I said *while* being pressed, When I'll change it back here?

Comment: Please read the documentation. You'll receive [`MotionEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)s in the `onTouch` method. Such `MotionEvent`s have different actions, e.g., [`ACTION_DOWN`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN) and [`ACTION_UP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_UP), which you can detect and act upon accordingly.

Comment: actually I read it after my comment :) you should be more detailed in your answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo for you
In java

```
name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    sp=getSharedPreferences("userdata",MODE_PRIVATE);
    speditor=sp.edit();

    log = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    log.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(name.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            {
                name.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid Username !!! :", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if((name.isFocusable()==true)||(pwd.isFocusable()==true))
            {
                name.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                pwd.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            if(pwd.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            {
                pwd.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid Password !!! :", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            String n,p;
            n=sp.getString("NAME","");
            p=sp.getString("PASWRD","");
            if((name.getText().toString().equals(n))&&(pwd.getText().toString().equals(p))){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Welcome "+name.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent nd=new Intent(getBaseContext(),DiaryActivity.class);
                startActivity(nd);
            }
        }
    });
    reg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(name.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            {
                name.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid Username !!! :", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if((name.isFocusable()==true)||(pwd.isFocusable()==true))
            {
                name.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                pwd.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            if(pwd.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            {
                pwd.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid Password !!! :", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if((!pwd.getText().toString().isEmpty())&&(!name.getText().toString().isEmpty())){
                speditor.putString("NAME",name.getText().toString());
                speditor.putString("PASWRD",pwd.getText().toString());
                speditor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Hello "+name.getText().toString()+" You are Registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just sample:

```
TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
  TextView  txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
```

and one button

```
 Button  btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View back_button)
            {
txt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
txt2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
}});
```

Here when the button clicked the background color of the textview change to black. Try like this for other properties